# microtype + siunitx and \micro - mysterious warnings

Tags: siunitx, warnings, microtype, font-encodings, textcomp

This code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI{10}{\micro\metre}

\end{document}
```

produces these warnings:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\textminus '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TS1' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `textcomp'.

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\texttrademark '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TS1' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `textcomp'.

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\textcopyright '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TS1' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `textcomp'.

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\textregistered '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TS1' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `textcomp'.

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\textdegree '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TS1' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `textcomp'.
```

Additional information:

- This seems only to happen when using `siunitx`'s "\micro" (like µm or µs)
- The errors also come up without `fontenc` and `lmodern` packages (but in the real world document where the warnings come up I use them, so I included them in the minimum example)
- loading the `textcomp` package make the warnings disappear

Questions:

- What exactly do these warnings mean?
- What exactly produces them?
- Should I just load the `textcomp` package? But it's from 1995 and I think it's obsolete. And I don't need it (appart from making the warnings disappear)
- What is the best solution here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To avoid messing up anything else in a document, `siunitx` is set up to avoid loading font packages and the like. As such, it uses its 'own' version of the `\textminus` and `\textmu`, and sets up a minimal amount of support for that. However, that confuses `microtype`, as you've seen (it should be harmless). Loading `textcomp` 'fixes' this as `siunitx` then uses the `textcomp` version of the two symbols, and `microtype` knows what is going on with that. I do recommend loading `textcomp` with `siunitx`, but it's not absolutely required so it's not enforced.

Comment: Thanks, but why does this happen only when using \micro? If I use for example \kilo\metre or \milli\metre this doesn't happen. Is it because \micro does involve a "non-common-letter" symbol ("µ")?

Comment: @FooBar Latin letters are automatically available with no font tricks, but the micro symbol (or indeed an upright mu) is not.