# unicode-math/mathspec interferes with siunitx

Tags: xetex, siunitx, unicode-math

## The Problem

I'm using `unicode-math` and the font TeX Gyre Pagella Math. Also, I use `siunitx` to denote my quantities. Unfortunately, the option `\micro` of `siunitx` doesn't get expanded to µ, but is dropped.

(The same behaviour can be observed when using `mathspec` in XeLaTeX)

## Minimal working example

Compile with Xe/LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\usepackage[mode = math]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\micro\m}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image: real]

### Expected output

> [image: expected]

Comment: You could do `\def\SIUnitSymbolMicro{\mu}` … but that doesn’t look like the right font settings (unslanted)?

Comment: I generated the expected output using `\mathrm{\mu m}`, so this means, there is an upright `\mu`.

Comment: What I meant is that it does look like the unslanted version of the italic glyph. The output is the same as yours with my definition.

Comment: According to [`unimath-symbols`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) this is the only upright `\mu`. Internally `siunitx` tries to associate `\textmu` to `\SIUnitSymbolMicro`.

Comment: I think the solution from [another answer about the µ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54915/16595) is the correct solution while using the non math version for the main text too: `\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}` (it uses the  special micro sign of UTF and not a mu).

Comment: Perfect. That looks great and blends nicely with all the latin letters. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54915/16595) by [nlogax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14354/nlogax) to [microtype + siunitx and \micro - mysterious warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74670/16595) Unicode has—besides the [Greek Small Letter Mu character µ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3bc/index.htm)—a special [Micro Sign µ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm).

That is to be used here. For some reason this is not present in `unicode-math`.
I assume that you also use TeX Gyre Pagella as your text font so we can use it from there with `\text`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\usepackage[mode = math]{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\micro\m}
\SI[mode=text]{10}{\micro\m} % just for reference
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Just for more information: the character can also be input in the `\sisetup` line as `^^b5`, if it's somehow difficult to use the Unicode character directly.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\usepackage[mode = math]{siunitx}
\def\SIUnitSymbolMicro{\textup{μ}}
\begin{document}


\SI{10}{\micro\m}
\end{document}
```

Note I needed to specify a text font as well.

[image]

Comment: Why `\def` and not `\cs_set:Npn \SIUnitSymbolMicro {\textup{μ}}`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel should be `\newcommand` probably. the packages use l3 internally but that doesn't mean you have to (or should) use l3 in the document preamble. `\def` is shorter than `\newcommand` so reduces the chance of a typo:-)