# unicode-math interferes with siunitx and ignore setting for complex unit

Tags: luatex, siunitx, unicode-math

I'm just trying to extend `\sisetup` by `output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\imath}` according to table 16 in [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. But the symbol `\imath` is missing in the output file, compiled by **lualatex**. See my MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{unicode-math} 
  % \usepackage{lualatex-math}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ,
        input-complex-roots = i,
        output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\imath}
    }

\begin{document}
  \num{1+2i} or \(\num{1+2i}\) test: \(\imath\)
  output
  \SI{10}{\micro\m}
  \SI[mode=text]{10}{\micro\m} % just for reference 

\end{document}
```

While the package [lualatex-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lualatex-math) works properly.  I found a similar question ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118894/unicode-math-mathspec-interferes-with-siunitx)), but unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loading an Upright Math Alphabet

With `unicode-math`, you can define an upright-math-symbols alphabet that’s distinct from text symbols in math mode.  Here is an example that sets the imaginary unit i in ISO style, from the upright italic font, but keeps the µ symbol from the main text font.

Using `\text` for symbols in math mode is a mistake I’ve made in the past—but then bold or italic formatting will bleed through from the surrounding text!  Here, you want to use `\mathrm`, but an alternative would be `\text{\normalfont µ}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math} 

  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
  \setmathfont[range=up]{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted}

  \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        math-micro=\mathrm{µ},text-micro=µ,
        input-complex-roots = i,
        output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\symup{i}}
    }

\begin{document}
  \num{1+2i} or \(\num{1+2i}\) test: \(\imath\)
  output
  \SI{10}{\micro\m}
  \SI[mode=text]{10}{\micro\m} % just for reference 

\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

Note that `\mathrm`, `\mathup`, `\operatorname` and so on use the default text font, while `\symup` uses the fancy upright-math-symbol font.

My go-to example is Euler’s identities, set with the constants in Hermann Zapf’s Neo Euler, with the remaining text in (clones of) his Palatino:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}, 
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler/Palatino sample]

### Using the Dotless ı

That doesn’t answer the literal question you asked, though, which was how to use dotless ı. Since the problem is that `siunitx` switches the font to `\mathrm`, just change it back.  The following works:

```
output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\mathnormal\imath}
```

If you use the technique above to load a math font with an upright dotless ı, `\symup\imath` will work as well.

### Changing \mathrm

Ulrike Fischer’s answer works great, but if you take that approach, I would recommend `\setmathrm` over `\setmathfontface\mathrm`.

Answer (score 3):

siunitx uses `\mathrm` for the typesetting of the number and as this is normally a text font it doesn't have the math symbols. You could map `\mathrm` to the math font:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfontface\mathrm{Latin Modern Math}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ,
        output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\imath},
    }

\begin{document}
  \num{1+2i} or \(\num{1+2i}\) test: $\imath$
  \SI{10}{\micro\m}
  \SI[mode=text]{10}{\micro\m} % just for reference
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend the `\setmathrm` command over `\setmathfontface`. It’s designed for this and also allows `BoldFont`, etc.

Comment: One mistake I’ve frequently made in the past: `\text` in math mode inherits the current text style, which might be bold, italic, etc. Either use `\symup` or `\text{\normalfont µ}`.

Comment: Also note that you can load an upright math alphabet distinct from the plain text font as `\symup`. E.g., `\setmathfont[range=up]{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted}` and `output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\symup i}`.