# siunitx overwrites the definition of ← and →

Tags: siunitx, input-encodings

This code

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2190}\leftarrow % ←
\begin{document}
    $←$
\end{document}
```

generates error

> ```
> Undefined control sequence \textleftarrow
> ```

How can this (that `←` is redefined as `textleftarrow`) happen without any warning?

Comment: Thanks @marmot. Thanks @PhelypeOleinik; and it seems `SIunits` defines `←` as well; just it does not overwrite my `DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `siunitx` uses the `TS1` encoding for some symbols. Somewhere in `siunitx.sty` you have:

```
\AtBeginDocument {
  \cs_if_free:cT { T@TS1 }
    {
      \DeclareFontEncoding { TS1 } { } { }
      \DeclareFontSubstitution { TS1 } { cmr } { m } { n }
    }
}
```

and this loads the `ts1enc.dfu` file which contains:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2190}{\textleftarrow}
```

which redefines the arrow, as you diagnosed.

In fact, without `siunitx`, the `utf8` macro for `←` is:

```
\u8:← ->\IeC {\leftarrow }
```

and *with* `siunitx` is is changed to:

```
\u8:← ->\IeC {\textleftarrow }
```

A hackish way of preventing `siunitx` from loading `ts1enc.dfu` is by tricking the `\cs_if_free:cT` with something like:

```
\def\T@TS1{\NothingUseful}
```

but right before posting the above as an answer, I found [this another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74673/134574) by Joseph Wright saying that if you load `textcomp`, `siunitx` will no longer load `ts1enc.dfu`, so you have:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2190}\leftarrow % ←
\begin{document}
    $←$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am satisfied with your explanation. Although I do not quite understand why `ts1enc.dfu` uses `\textleftarrow` as a substitute while the later is undefined.

Comment: @Symbol1 Curious indeed... Maybe it's supposed to be used by font packages which define `\textleftarrow`.